# По-Арининому, но по-арински?

Tags: орфография

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Лопатин говорит, что наречия, образованные от имён собственных, пишутся с большой буквы, и он нам даёт примеры наречий, которые через дефис пишутся и **которые все оканчиваются на -ому**.

Розенталь, однако-с, говорит, что такои наречия все пишутся с маленькой буквы, и он нам даёт примеры наречий, тоже через дефис пишущихся, но, что самое главное, **на -ски оканчивающихся**.

Из-за всего этого я сейчас даже не знаю, как писать по-правильному следующие наречия, т. е. заглавную или строчную букву таки ли использовать. Можете мне помочь, пожалуйста?

Вот мои наречия (все с маленькой буквы написанные): *по-ариненому, по-арински, по-аристархово-леопольдовски, по-мистера-георгиевски, по-тёти-ларисеному, по-пушкиному, по-пушкински*.

введите сюда описание изображения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Однозначно: *Арин**и**н, Ларис**и**н.*

Comment: Да, и причём эта буква "и" к обоим случаям относится.

Comment: Дело в том, что составители правил 56 этот момент упустили. Об этом писал Лопатин. Если смогу, дам ссылку.

Answer (score 4):

**Не все формы**  прилагательных и наречий возможны.

Правильно:

(1) **Арина (девочка)**  — Аринины игрушки,  все должно быть по-Арининому.

(2) **тетя Арина** — тети-Аринин дом, по-тети-Арининому.

(3)  **Арина Петровна** —  Арины-Петровнин дом, по Арины-Петровниному.

(4) **Известный поэт Аринин,** вроде Пушкина. Тогда арининская  поэзия, арининский стиль,  Арининские вечера,  по-аринински кратко и выразительно.

**От нарицательных имен:** аринский язык (енисейская группа) – по-арински, материнский – по-матерински.

**Грамматическая справка**

От имен собственных образуются:

(1) относительные прилагательные с помощью суффиксов  ОВ/ЕВ, ИН,

(2) относительно-притяжательные прилагательные с суффиксом СК,

(3) наречия на СКИ.

Прилагательные могут писаться как с прописной, так и со строчной буквы, а наречия на СКИ всегда пишутся со строчной буквы.

**Материалы по теме**

[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=16#pp16)

[ПАС под ред. Лопатина § 166 – 167](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=83#pp83)

Comment: Конкретно. Здорово. Я бы до морковкина заговенья возилась с объяснениями...

Comment: Спасибо, Римма!   Это новые технологии, как бы... ))  До морковкина заговенья?..  Интересно почитать:  https://dzen.ru/a/XbJzUvVX0ADEQ1Xz

Comment: *Прилагательные могут писаться как с прописной, так и со строчной буквы* — вот видите, вы здесь правильно написали, а не с "или" (*Прилагательные **могут** писаться с прописной или строчной буквы*). И надо же сказать, когда с какой.

Comment: Здесь нужен именно двойной союз по ситуации.

Comment: А там похожие ситуации (*можно, возможно*).